# How to hide enemy when hit in slick2d

Tags: java, image, game-engine, slick2d

I'm creating a 2d game in slick and im having a bit of trouble when a bullet hits an enemy
The bullet hits the enemy and it registers as being dead- but I don't know how to remove the enemy image from the screen. Below is the code:

This is in the render method:

```
      for(Zombie z: zombies){       

        if(!z.isDead()){
            z.render(gc, sbg, g);
        }

    }
```

all i have in the Zombie render method is

```
     g.drawImage(zombie, 100, 100);
```

I'm sure it will be something simple, but after a while of searching I'm struggling to find anything relevant - any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Don't draw this ennemy on the next screen update : `the render()` function should not be called if the ennemy is dead.

Comment: That's the thing I'm not calling the render method if the zombie is dead - but it still shows it for some reason?

Comment: Clear the current frame before drawing the next?

Comment: Fill your screen with a unique color and redraw the entire scene.

Comment: ahhh sorry for wasting everyone's time! In the render method I was creating a new zombie object everytime so it was just showing another instance, forgot I'd put that in there!Sorry

Comment: @matto If you solved your own question, post the solution so when someone who has a similar question comes here, they don't have to dig through comments.